# wso2 esb redeployment custom mediator

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

We are investigating whether or not we can use the WSO2 - ESB as our new platform.

With our current esb we connect external systems to each other over different channels like JMS,FTP,JDBC.
Most of the interfaces are independent of each other. The number of interfaces we have now is about 300.

The processing in each interface consists of : 
- connecting to the external systems
- logging the in + outgoing messages
- transformation of the incoming message into an outgoing message.

The transformation of the message is programmed in java.

Since the interfaces are independent of each other, it is not an option for us to stop other interfaces
when we need to deploy a new ( or modified existing ) interface.

What I understood from WSO2 esb is that when using a custom mediator to transform I have to restart the WSO2 - ESB server
when the implementation of the custom mediator changes.
This is not what we want unless it is the only interface running on this esb server.

What are my options given these constraints:

- The update of an existing interface should not have any impact on other interfaces.
- The transformation of the messages is programmed in Java.
- The number of interfaces is around 300.

Answer (score 0):

Usually WSO2 ESB has [rich set of mediators](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB450/Mediators) to handle transformation and perform mediation it seems you need more than that. You can use Developer Studio, Eclipse based IDE to add a custom mediator without restarting the server. please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316034/wso2-carbon-studio-uploading-a-class-mediator-to-esb) for more details.